# C# Download html page to a string AS IS?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, download

Why  WebClient or HttpWebResponce/Request have different encodings compare to when I'm looking in a page source in my browser? Plus if they couldn't find proper Encoding they shows me weird symbols. For instance: when I'm trying to download -  http://www.li.ru  - in page source it's utf-8, and from WebClient or HttpWebResponce/Request it's windows-1251.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to force the encoding to be the same on the webpage you request.

With WebClient you do the following:

```
using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string s = webClient.DownloadString("http://wwww.li.ru");
}
```

With HttpWebResponse/Request:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.li.ru");
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Just extend the fixed encoding to the following code:

```
var enc = Encoding.Default;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.CharacterSet))
{
    var charSet = response.CharacterSet;
    if (charSet == "ISO-8859-1")
        charSet = "windows-1251";

    enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(charSet);
}

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream, enc);
return reader.ReadToEnd();
```

For further explanation you can give this page a look:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/feroze_daud/archive/2004/03/30/104440.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but what if I have several pages with different Encoding... It'll make other pages unreadable.

Comment: This works better, but still have one left... http://www.jino.ru - it still shows me strange symbols.

Comment: Yeah the ISO-8859-1 and/or Windows 1251 is a bit a pain in the ass, but when you implement the code from the posted page you wont have a problem. Its reading the charset direclty from the resulting page.

You could also simply ask if the response.CharacterSet = ISO-8859-1 and translate it to windows-1251, this than should solve the problem aswell.

In HTML5 specs its even mentiod that you should treat the ISO-8859-1 as it was the windows 1251.